# Change a table class by clicking on popover content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table which cells class I want to have changeable. The idea is I click on a table cell and then I select a class from popover content. For that I use a jQuery plugin [WebUI Popover](http://sandywalker.github.io/webui-popover/demo/). The selected class should be written (or rewritten) into the cell I clicked on before.

Example code is on **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jbhpaw9e/)**. It might looks like a color picker but it is not.

### The problem:

I don't know how to realize the communication with the plugin class. The code for changing the cell class should be as follows:

`$(this).$('td').removeClass().addClass('class_I_selected_from_popover_content');`

But I don't know how to connect it with the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common approach when using plugins would be to tap into the events exposed by the plugin.

```
$('#myTable td').webuiPopover({
        title: '',
        content: '<a href="#" class="redClass"><span>change to red class</span></a> <a href="#" class="blueClass"><span>change to blue class</span></a> <a href="#" class="greenClass"><span>change to green class</span></a> <a href="#" class="grayClass"><span>change to gray class</span></a>',
        closeable: true,
        width: 200,
        arrow: true,
        placement: 'auto'
    }).on('show.webui.popover hide.webui.popover', function(e){
        $('td.active-cell').removeClass('active-cell');
        $(this).addClass('active-cell');            
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.webui-popover-content a', function(){
        $('td.active-cell')
              .removeClass('redClass grayClass blueClass greenClass')
              .addClass( $(this).attr('class'));
    });
```

Above will toggle the class `active-cell` when popover is shown and hidden.

The suggestions of adding another click handler can cause bugs due to secondary clicks that may change things unexpectedly

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbhpaw9e/6/)**</kbd>

Comment: for some reason `active-cell` doesnt get removed after clicking a few squares  in the demo but a much better approach

Comment: what browser? Works fine for me. Can see it is gone when close popover

Comment: Chrome Version 40.0.2214.115 (64-bit) on a Mac, if I use it a few times, like changing 3 or 4 different squares, the `active-cell` class stops getting removed and 2-3 cells change when selecting the class from the list

Comment: but the `active-cell` remains in code when I click on another cell without closing the current popover by "X" button

Comment: yep, it happens when you dont close the menu, since it's tied to that event, maybe need to auto-close it when a class is selected

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to use this plugin but I have some trick to solve this solution.

I hope it works as you need.

```js
var flag = null;
$(document).ready(function ($) {        
    $('#myTable td').webuiPopover({
        title: '',
        content: '<a href="#" class="redClass"><span>change to red class</span></a> <a href="#" class="blueClass"><span>change to blue class</span></a> <a href="#" class="greenClass"><span>change to green class</span></a> <a href="#" class="grayClass"><span>change to gray class</span></a>',
        closeable: true,
        width: 200,
        arrow: true,
        placement: 'auto'
    }).click(function(){
        flag = $(this);
    });
    
    $('body').on('click', 'a', function(){
        var newClass = $(this).attr('class');
        flag.removeClass().addClass(newClass);
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice, this is what I needed :)